# What is the first line number in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, line-numbers

I don't want to have to download and install eclipse on this machine, but for you who do have it, what is the first line on the Eclipse IDE?  On the left after you enable line numbers in the left hand column, the first number is?

Comment: Why do you want to know?  Just curious.

Comment: Unless it's counting in base 0, why should it be anything other than 1?

Comment: I am making a suggestion for an app developed by my company.  The app starts with displaying code with the first line as 0 and I was making sure that Visual Studio, Eclipse, and other IDEs start with line 1 so my comment would be valid.

Comment: I hope you win your point.  Usually counting/numbering starts at 1, offsets start at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Java source editor, at least, the first line number is 1.